# PCI error during ubuntu bootup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound, pci

[My System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqyW4.png)

My system is on dual-boot with windows 11 and Ubuntu. Ever since i installed Ubuntu i am getting this error during the bootup process.

[During Ubuntu Bootup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP88f.jpg)

2/4 speakers are undetectable to the OS. Working for the Windows though.

Now, i looked answers for `ACPI BIOS error`, according to them i need not worry about it.
But i am worried about the `PCI error`.

**SOlUTION I TRIED [DIDN'T WORK]**

I am new to using linux, so what i did might be useless.

I checked my system log for pci error.

[My log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTXCk.jpg)

Thing that caught my eye.

`Jul  8 10:17:34 ubuntu fwupd[2141]: 04:47:34:0450 FuEngine             failed to add device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.5/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/mtd/mtd0ro: attribute size returned no data`

I tried upgrading fwupd, but i got error that i have unreolved dependencies. Resolve them. Upgraded it, But still it didn't work.

Comment: I think you haven't to worry about  the PCI error message, the message cames from your kernel, and have something to do with the bios. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209943


For your sound issue could you provide information about which and how do you connect the speakers?